# Visual C++ 14 - cannot build a simple thread program which builds on Visual C++ 12

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

I have this MCVE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Foo
{
    void bar_i() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }

public:
    void bar()
    {
        // I don't know why I used std::ref(*this) instead of this, I wrote this some time ago
        std::thread t(&Foo::bar_i, std::ref(*this));
        t.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
}
```

which builds on VS 2013 Update 3 and [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cd833b41f3d4d2a), but does not build on VS 2015 with this error list:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Callable=void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Types={std::reference_wrapper<Foo>}'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(247): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1>(std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(247): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1>(std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(242): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(230): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(256): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thread(52): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>>>>
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\c++ active\tests\tests\test.cpp(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__thiscall Foo::* )(void),std::reference_wrapper<Foo>,void>(_Fn &&,std::reference_wrapper<Foo> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void)
1>          ]
```

If not for the `std::ref`, this code would compile. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the rules in 20.9.2 cause your code to be equivalent to

```
auto f = &Foo::bar_i;
decay<decltype(std::ref(*this))>::type t1 = std::ref(*this); // still reference_wrapper
((*t1).*f)();
```

which is in fact an error.

Just use `std::thread t(&Foo::bar_i, this);`, since the pointer-to-member-function machinery present in `std::thread` knows to dereference the first parameter when performing the call.

According to the draft [n4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) I'm looking at, the special handling of `std::reference_wrapper` used by `std::bind` (see 20.9.10.3) is not applied to `std::thread`.  Neither is the special decay logic used by `std::tuple`, which causes `reference_wrapper` to become a normal reference.

Comment: Can you please link/quote the standard? I still don't get why it would compile with other compilers.

Comment: @LogicStuff: I added a link.  The terminology around this has changed somewhat between C++11/C++14/C++1z, so it's possible that the compilers have correctly implemented different rules.